# G suite login issues

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

when I create an account in google admin and try to login into that account, it fails and redirects me to google admin portal. The error message that I get is that **"We are sorry, but you do not have access to Email. Please contact your Organization Administrator for access."** What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your domain is still unverified with G Suite, https://support.google.com/a/answer/60216?hl=en
2. Email could be disabled form the APPS option within the G Suite Admin Panel, https://support.google.com/a/answer/57919

that in case you are login to gmail, otherwise if you are not an admin and are trying to login to admin.google.com you should be redirected somewhere else instead the admin portal. The same thing happens when a service is not enabled on the Admin Console.